# Prove that W is a subspace of U, but they do not coincide (U has more elements).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V = M_{22}(\Bbb R)$ be the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with real entries. If A = \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
is an element of $V$ , then $\mathrm{tr}\, A = a + d$ is called the trace of $A$.

$W = \{A \in V \mid A^T = - A\}$, $U = \{A \in V \mid \mathrm{tr}\, A =0\}$ are subspaces of $V$.

I have already proved that $U$, $W$ are subspaces of $V$ and that $W$ is a subspace of $U$, but how do I go about proving that they do not coincide?

Comment: $W$ is not a subspace of $A$. Why would a symmetric matrix have a zero trace?

Comment: Maybe you mean A^T=-A$?

Comment: Yeah, I meant $A^T$= - A

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 1):

If $A^T=-A$ then for all diagonal elements, we find $a_{ii}=-a_{ii}$, i.e., $a_{ii=0}$ and in particular $\operatorname{tr} A=\sum_i a_{ii}=0$. Thus $W$ is a subspace of $U$.

To show that it is a proper subspace, it suffices to exhibit a single matrix that trace $=0$, but not all diagonal elements $=0$. can you see a way to have $a_{11}+a_{22}=0$ with $a_{11}\ne 0$?

Answer (score 0):

$W$ is not a subspace of $U$. The matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2  \\
        2 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

is symmetric and we have $\mathrm{tr}\, A = 2$.

Therefore $U$ and $W$ do not coincide; for another example, find a non-symmetric matric with trace $0$. This is straightforward.

Comment: Or, as $W$ is not even a subspace of $U$, we already know they do not coincide ...

Comment: Yes, indeed that is enough.

Comment: The question has changed: $W$ consists of the antisymmetric matrices.